# Format values in a Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Is there any way to format the values that are bound to a datagrid? For example I have the following:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="487" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="dgTransactionLog" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="404">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Date}" Header="Date" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Payee1.Name}" Header="To/From" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Amount}" Header="Amount" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I'd like the Date column to be just date (not time) and the Amount column to be currency format.  Here's how I populate the datagrid:

```
var transactions = TransactionManager.GetTransactions();
dgTransactionLog.ItemsSource = transactions;
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use the `StringFormat` property:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat=d}" Header="Date" />
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat=C}" Header="Amount" />
```

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

One easiest way. here in the code below use your language code as a value of ConverterCulture.
you can find your language [code here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488%28v=cs.20%29.aspx)

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Profit, ConverterCulture='gu-IN' ,StringFormat=c}" Header="Profit" Width="*" MinWidth="80" FontWeight="Normal"/>
```

the output will be in your local currency [image: output screenshot]

for anything other than currency find stringFormat specifier [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString)

Answer (score 0):

If the stringformat is variable, the above solutions will not work.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="YTemplate">
        <Label Content="{Binding Y, Mode=OneWay}" ContentStringFormat="{Binding StringFormat, ElementName=Parent_UC}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Y" Width="*" CellTemplate="{StaticResource YTemplate}"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```