# format values in datagrid to other currency

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I need to ask follow up question from this thread 
[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299329/format-values-in-a-datagrid/18081100#18081100)

how to change the currency to other format, ie. in my case using Indonesian Rupiah (IDR)

Comment: You'll need to set the CultureInfo : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688126.aspx

Comment: Or if it's single instance you could just attach it via `StringFormat` like `Binding="{Binding Blah, StringFormat='Rp\{0\}'}"` though I suppose I should maybe be putting this stuff as an answer instead of a comment :/

Comment: Chris W. Would you mind putting the comment into the answer. That's the correct answer.

Comment: Sure thing, I'm always good with mooching some easy pointage. Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to go with setting your [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688126.aspx) or if it's for single instance you can just apply it via a `StringFormat` like;

```
Binding="{Binding Blah, StringFormat='Rp\{0\}'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To display currency you need basically two things:

- currency formatting rule saying where and how the currency symbol is placed by the number, how the negative numbers are represented etc. - this is performed using CultureInfo and in XAML by setting ConverterCulture in Binding
- set the proper currency symbol - if it is the same as your CultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, than you have nothing to worry about otherwise you have to create copy of CultureInfo and change it

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solutions and I went with this way.

```
 <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="unitPriceColumn" Binding="{Binding UnitPrice, StringFormat=C, ConverterCulture=id-ID}" Header="Unit Price" Width="SizeToHeader"/>
```

You can also set the current culture to the current thread