# Adding a dot separator instead of comma in datagrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, number-formatting

I have a datagrid column that shows int values from the database.
The output looks like this:

4,561,876.

I need it to look like this:

4.561,876.

I tried with to put in my Main() `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(3098);` , but it shows no results.

This is my formating in the xaml for the cell:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Ulaz, StringFormat={}{0:n2}}" Width="Auto" Header="Column"/>
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31898389/1997232) helpful?

Comment: What is the actual value and type of the Ulaz property?

Comment: type is int from the sql server database

Comment: Int? So the actual value is 4561876? So you basically want to replace the first (only) thousand separator with a dot?

Comment: @Sinatr that is it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `xml:lang` to `DataGridTextColumn` to appropriate culture to set the control's value in the specific culture.