# WPF DataGrid sorting data of type "double"

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have run into a problem

that I **want to sort a "*double*"** value in the DataGrid, these values are known to be **stored as "*string*"**.

When I press sort (on the header), then it sorts the data from the column "money total" **as type "*string*"**.

(see here)

[image: The "moneyTotal" column]

Thats my DataGridTextColumn (unfortunately there is no DataGridDoubleColumn)

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{DynamicResource moneyTotal}" Binding="{Binding StringMoneyTotal}"/>
```

Thats my Model (have removed the unimportant code)

```
public class InvoiceModel
{
    public double MoneyTotal { get; set; }
    public string StringMoneyTotal { get { return String.Format("{0:0.0,0}", MoneyTotal); }} 
}
```

Is there a solution how I can really sort by double? unfortunately the current sorting is useless

Comment: You should bind the double property and use string format to do the currency formatting.

Comment: Add `SortMemberPath="MoneyTotal"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format values in a Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299329/format-values-in-a-datagrid)

Comment: @KlausGütter I'm embarrassed. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to fix this:

1. As suggested by Andy in the comments, just bind to `MoneyTotal` (no need for  StringMoneyTotal) and provide the formatting separately, e.g.: `Binding="{Binding MoneyTotal, StringFormat={}{0:0.00}}"`. Alternatively to `StringFormat`you could also use a `Converter`.
2. Keep the binding as is, but specify by which property to sort: `SortMemberPath="MoneyTotal"`